# Mutliple forms, form submissions and calculations

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms

I have the following scenario and I wonder how to make the best custom module or if there are some contributed modules I could use for this.

#### Scenario:

> I have a site with 100+ different forms and a contact info form in each form.
> An anonymous user submits one form. This form needs to be sent to the correct **users** of Role A and have **the same tag** in their profile as the form. So, not all users with Role A get to see the submitted form.
>
> All these users then can fill in a comment field and number field. All users can see the lowest number.
>
> After X time an email will be sent to the anonymous user (contact info form) with the number and comment of the user with the **lowest** number.

#### Questions:

1. What is the best way to build this in Drupal? I was thinking with entity forms but how to tag form (like a taxonomy) and get it **only sent/viewed** to users with **that tag**? Also, each form needs to have the **contact info form**.
2. How can users send comment and number for this submitted form (only lowest 5 numbers need to be saved in database + comment field).
3. After X time send email to email address (from contact info form) with the lowest number and comment.

Comment: Which Drupal version?

Comment: Drupal 7 A college told me to make 1 webfrom with all the fields of the 100 forms